# Bigcommerce Stencil External Access Url Fails to Load Page for Testing

Tags: url, testing, ip-address, bigcommerce, external-url

Whenever I run `stencil start` in my terminal, I'd say that 90% of the time I try to visit the external URL (something like this - http://192.168.1.146:3000) it gives me alongside my local address (http://localhost:3000) it fails to load the page on my testing devices and all browsers. I've looked and looked, but I can seem to find what is causing the issue. Anybody run into this problem before?

Comment: I haven't heard reports of this, but you should look into troubleshooting browsersync which provides this functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me somewhere to start! @Alyss